# SVG display bug in different browsers

Tags: php, xml, svg

On my server, I did a remote XSLT tranformation in php like this:

```
$command = $java . $saxon . $target2 . ' ' . $xsl2.' '.$param;

passthru($command, $result);
```

the $target2 is an input SVG file and $xsl2 is the stylesheet, saxon is the saxon8.jar file, and I've tested it with several broswers.

In Google Chrome, everything worked perfect, the SVG graph got shown correctly.

However, I tried to do the same thing in Firefox(which should supports SVG graph), no SVG graph got shown, but only the actual code for the SVG graph was shown. I used "viewsource" to check out the first and last few lines of the generated SVG in firefox, and it read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<!--  Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build  14948)  --> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0"  
 .......
</svg>
```

I tried using FireBug to debug, and there is `html` tags and `head` and `body` tags shown, is is saying I am screwing up my SVG with HTML stuff?

I am kinda stuck here, thanks in advance for your guys' help!

Comment: When you look at the response body and content-type header (!) in firebug, what do you see?

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks, I got this problem fixed, I was missing the header file.

Comment: Please write up your solution as an answer and then accept it. That's much more useful to other users of this site than just deleting your question!

Comment: Retagging because there is no transformation question nor problem. This is because media type header as you already have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add a content type header file like:

```
header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
```

add it to the front of the php file, and everything should work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's answer works well in PHP, but it could be achieved without help of PHP already on server side before PHP interpreter kicks in. 
Here as an example on Apache's `httpd.conf` / `.htaccess`, taken from HTML5BoilerPlate's [*Apache HTTP server boilerplate*](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache).

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Proper MIME types for all files                                            |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Extension may be specified w or w/o leading dot
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  # SVG
  #   Required for svg webfonts on iPad
  #   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
  AddType image/svg+xml                       svg svgz
  AddEncoding gzip                            svgz
</IfModule>
```